# how do i call methods from another class in android?

Tags: android

I have two classes in question. Both extend Activity.

Class A

```
public void displayinfo() 
{
setContentView(R.layout.dynamicinfo);
//Add some buttons dynamically here
//do some processing
// move on to Class B
}
```

In Class B: I want to go back to Class A state in UI if BACK button is pressed.

Class B

```
//Register a listener for this button
Backbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
Log.i("setOnClickListener", "Pressed Back Button ");
Toast.makeText(mycontext, "Pressed Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//HERE I want to go back class's function in UI as well as restoring the sttae for that screen.
}
```

how do I do that?
I looked around some questions.
they did not answer clearly what I am looking for.hence the posting.

thanks.I think I was adding my own Back button on the Layout I created in the Class B's UI Screen --not using the regular "Back" button on the key board. May be that was the problem.

Comment: it's not clear what are you trying to do.    android's default behaiviour when back button pressed is to pop the previous activity from stack on the state it's been before. in this case the onResume() method from "activity A" would be called

Comment: thanks.I think I was adding my own Back button on the Layout I created in the Class B's UI Screen --not using the regular "Back" button on the key board. May be that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both class A and class B are activities, and class B activity is started from class A activity, then you should only finish() you class B activity then you should return to class A with its state preserved.

I am not sure if you are asking this as this seems a very basic android activity flow.

Comment: My problem us when I get the control back to Class A, the dynamically created buttons and their handlers are all gone.

Comment: @PhaniGargey if this is the case then you probably need to redo the dynamic layout in the `onResume()`

Answer (score 1):

Class A :

```
public void displayinfo() 
{
setContentView(R.layout.dynamicinfo);
//Add some buttons dynamically here
//do some processing
// move on to Class B

/*For starting activity B use this code*/
Intent in=new Intent(this,CalssB.class);
startActivity(in);

}
```

now in class B you just need to finish activity B code :

```
Backbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
Log.i("setOnClickListener", "Pressed Back Button ");
Toast.makeText(mycontext, "Pressed Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

/* This  will finish current activity B and back to activity A with same state.*/
finish();
}
```

refer this link for understand in details.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: thanks.I think I was adding my own Back button on the Layout I created in the Class B's UI Screen --not using the regular "Back" button on the key board. May be that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps you to navigate your activity from Class B to Class A when back button is pressed.

ClassA.java

```
/***********/
startActivity(new Intent(ClassA.this,CalssB.class);
```

ClassB.java

```
   @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        finish();
         //startActivity(new Intent(ClassB.this,ClassA.class));
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backbutton pressed", 30).show();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

This code is used of for back button.... 
If in button click you need to navigate page to ClassA means use anyone of the below code..

ClassB.java

```
  btn.onClick(){

        finish(); 
          (or)
         startActivity(new Intent(ClassB.this,ClassA.class));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you **move** to `ClassB` ?  You can move to the `ClassB` with an `Intent`.

```
public void displayinfo() 
{
  setContentView(R.layout.dynamicinfo);

  //move on to Class B like this:
  Intent k = new Intent(this, ClassA.class);
  startActivity(k);
}
```

Now when you have moved to `ClassB`, and the **Back** button is pressed it will automatically move to `ClassA`

Comment: thanks.I think I was adding my own Back button on the Layout I created in the Class B's UI Screen --not using the regular "Back" button on the key board. May be that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what was wrong.
From each activity I was calling a finish() before invoking the next  activity via Intent mechanism.
And hence when the Back button was pressed from different activities, there was nothing to go to.
And hence the APP used to crash.

Thanks for all kind responses.
Much appreciated.
As always, learnt something new from each of the response.

I fixed it by removing the finish() in the activities that need to be present.
I didnt have to re-do or re-build the UI (even the dynamic buttons). :-)

Answer (score -1):

in class b add

```
function addReturn(ClassA back){
// back.take over the control
}
```

i would use an interfase or extension if you want to be flexible for your viewports.

in Class a before pass control over you need to add ’this’ to the b class.